# Rendering image causes zoom in and texture turns the scene black

Tags: texturing, image

I'm trying to apply texture to an object but when I render the image it does this: [image]

When I switch to texture display it does this:

[image]

Can anyone explain what's happening and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain which result is as expected and which is not? Note that Textured shading doesn't have any effect on the rendered result if that's what the question is about.

Comment: Just to point out a (sort of) contributing factor you may be unaware of—you’re rendering with the Blender render engine, not Cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Based off of these images, this is a simple matter of your outdoor scene being unlit.  In Blender 2.79, press <kbd>spacebar</kbd> type "add lamp", and choose "Sun" in the resulting menu.  Feel free to add other lights as appropriate.